# Generic React TypeScript component with 'as' prop (able to render any valid dom node)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have this working as expected in the below example, my question is - is there anyway i can rewrite this so that i don't have to pass both a generic `T` and the `as` prop. I would ideally like to just pass the `as` prop and have the component's prop interface use that.

Is this possible in TypeScript?

```js
export type Props<
  T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
> = JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] & {
  as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
}

export const MyComponent = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>({
  as: Component = 'div',
}: Props<T>) => {
   // Stuff
   return <Component />
}


// Usage
const Anchor = () => <MyComponent<'a'> href='foo' as='a' id='bar' />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fairly easy to implement the second variant — the one where an explicit type argument is required:

**Solution one**

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props<K extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = JSX.IntrinsicElements[K];

declare class MyComponent<K extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> extends React.Component<Props<K>> {}

<MyComponent<'a'> href="https://example.com/" id="myLink" />;
```

**Solution two**

When it comes to the first variant, it's more tricky. What you want is not a generic component, but a union of props. To illustrate why, let's consider a concrete example when `MyComponent` handles only a union of `a` and `button`.

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props =
   | ({ as: 'a' } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'])
   | ({ as: 'button' } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['button']);

declare class MyComponent<T extends 'a' | 'button'> extends React.Component<Props> {}

<MyComponent as="a" href="https://example.com" />; // ✔ OK
<MyComponent as="button" href="https://example.com" />; // ✘ Compile-time error
```

`MyComponent` doesn't have to be generic in order to recognize which props it should receive. The `as` prop is a sufficient discriminant.

We can generalize this example by creating a union of all tags and their respective props:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  [K in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]: { as: K } & JSX.IntrinsicElements[K];
}[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements];

declare class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {}

<MyComponent as="a" href="https://example.com" />; // ✔ OK
<MyComponent as="button" href="https://example.com" />; // ✘ Compile-time error
```

---

This will get the job done, as it's the same as if we defined our union manually. However, creating such a huge union has downsides:

- IntelliSense becomes painfully slow
- Error messages become cryptic
- The overall complexity increases.

Just something to be aware of! ;)

Comment: How would you set `button` as default so that if you don't pass `as: 'a'` you can't pass `href`?