# How to properly extend a type so that its key can be used as an index in a dependent attribute in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with TypeScript and want to do the following manipulation:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './SocialNetwork.module.scss'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { FontAwesomeIcon, type FontAwesomeIconProps } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

// Generic A doesn't work the way I want it to
export type SocialNetworkProps<A extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = FontAwesomeIconProps & {
  className?: string
  // I need that if a key from JSX.IntrinsicElements was transferred, then I pull the appropriate type of props from the same type, but already by key.
  as?: A | React.FC,
  asProps?: JSX.IntrinsicElements[A]
}

// In my approach, I need to pass the generic here, and I want it to depend on what the user passed in props
const SocialNetwork: React.FC<SocialNetworkProps> = ({ className, icon, as = 'a', asProps, ...rest }): JSX.Element => {
  const CostumTag = as

  return (
    <CostumTag className={classNames(styles.socialNetwork, className)}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} {...rest} />
    </CostumTag>
  )
}

export default SocialNetwork
```

How should I do it, so that when the `as='div'` or `as='a'` field is passed to the component, the `asProps` type is pulled as `JSX.IntrinsicElements['a']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question can be considered a duplicate, since there is already an answer to this question, the truth is that in my case, the implementation is a bit easier because I don’t have ...rest that were supposed to be read dynamically, here is the code of how I did it, and it works great for me:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './SocialNetwork.module.scss'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { FontAwesomeIcon, type FontAwesomeIconProps } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export type SocialNetworkProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = FontAwesomeIconProps & {
  className?: string
  as?: T
  asProps?: JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
}

const SocialNetwork = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>({
  className,
  icon,
  as,
  asProps,
  ...rest
}: SocialNetworkProps<T>): JSX.Element => {
  const CostumTag = (as as React.ElementType) || 'a'

  return (
    <CostumTag className={classNames(styles.socialNetwork, className)} {...asProps}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} {...rest} />
    </CostumTag>
  )
}

export default SocialNetwork
```

And here are the links to the references I looked at to write my code:

1. Similar question on stackoverflow - [Generic React TypeScript component with 'as' prop (able to render any valid dom node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200824/generic-react-typescript-component-with-as-prop-able-to-render-any-valid-dom)
2. An article with a detailed description of how to implement it (which is where I started) - https://blog.andrewbran.ch/polymorphic-react-components/
3. A library that already does something similar, but I will not delve into it - https://blog.andrewbran.ch/polymorphic-react-components/